# DB2 "Error in converting column name from JString to CString"

Tags: jdbc, db2, federation, db2-zos, adabas

We are setting up the federation in order to browse data from ADABAS using DB2 federation. We have a Classic Data Architect connection set up and a remote server in DB2 federation configured using JDBC. The problem is that when we try to create a nickname using this command:

CREATE NICKNAME "JADABAS"."[TABLENAME]" FOR "CACDSJ"."ANAG"."[TABLENAME]";
we are getting this error:

> The SQL statement or command failed because of a database system
>   error. (Reason "Error in converting column name from JString to
>   CString".). SQLCODE=-901, SQLSTATE=     , DRIVER=3.68.61

The DB2-server is a windows.

If we perform a select using the command

```
db2 set passthru CACDSJ
db2 select * from "ANAG"."[TABLENAME]"
```

The query is executed without any problem

Comment: If you failed to create the nickname, I expect you still have permissions/privileges issues.  Edit your question to include what messages appear in db2diag when you run create nickname.

Comment: Also, in your 'CREATE SERVER' you can (temporarily only) try the 'JDBC LOG' 'Y' option and examine what messages the wrapper creates in the DIAGPATH of your Db2-instance.

Comment: I have already done that but there is nothing about that error

Comment: If you enabled the jdbc logging on the create-server , and then dropped (if exist) and recreate the nickname, and still the jdbc wrapper shows no entries in its logfile for 'create nickname' then you should open a trouble-ticket with IBM